# How does MySQL find rows with a given content?

Tags: mysql, select

I am wondering how MySQL finds the rows in a table when searching like so:

```
select * from table where field = 'text';
```

Does it use a particular search algorithm? Is it practically the fastest way to look up information in a table? Or would building a search macro using another algorithm (like Boyer-Moore) work faster?

Comment: Note that whatever external search you use, it's probably not going to be faster than searching in the db except in certain edge cases. The db implementations out there (such as in MySQL) have spent a lot of energy on making lookups efficient. Any algorithm you use still has to rely on the db to send you the data, which will be your bottleneck. Remember: premature optimization is the source of all evil.

Answer (score 3):

If there is an index on field, then databases often use a b-tree for indexed searches. If there is no index, then the entire table is scanned. This describes some of the techniques used in MySql

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-btree-hash.html

Many hours of work has gone into optimizing MySql. Take advantage of that work already done, and resist trying to re-doing it

Answer (score 1):

For that query it can do nothing other than searching every entry of that table and comparing its field column against that string.

Boyer-Moore isn't needed because it's exact equality that's requested and not asking whether the field contains that string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in how it found those records try executing using the EXPLAIN keyword:

```
EXPLAIN select * from table where field = 'text';
```

I would recommend looking at [this article](http://weevilgenius.net/2010/09/mysql-explain-reference/) to get a better understanding what is happening in the background.

I would be very surprised if you would be able to write something on your own that is faster.  You could look at creating indexes on the table in question to speed up selects.